# NoSuchMethodError: org.docx4j.org.apache.xml.serializer.SerializerFactory.getSerializer

Tags: java, docx4j, nosuchmethoderror

Maven Dependency

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>de.phip1611</groupId>
            <artifactId>docx4j-search-and-replace-util</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3</version>
        </dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>docx4j</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

My Code is look like this as mentioned below.

```
 WordprocessingMLPackage sourceDocxDoc = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(fileInputStream) ;
 ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 HashMap<String, String> replace = new HashMap<String, String>();
 replace.put("$Tag1","My Db Data");
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 Docx4JSRUtil.searchAndReplace(sourceDocxDoc, replace);
 sourceDocxDoc.save(out);
```

program runs successfully on local environment but sometimes getting exception on production environment as per attached image on line sourceDocxDoc.save(out);

I can't debug it on local environment, so anyone else experienced this issue while using Docx4j lib to replace MS Word file contains identifier with data.

Java Experts kindly respond.............

[Exception Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53zsh.png)

[Same issue found at this link](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j-ImportXHTML/issues/61)

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved by my self

instead of using below maven dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>docx4j</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.2</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

I changed to below maven dependency and it works.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>docx4j-JAXB-ReferenceImpl</artifactId>
        <version>8.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>docx4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>8.1.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```